# Getting a channel by its ID

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to send a message to a specific channel in a Discord server using discord.js, but when I try to find the channel it returns `undefined`.

I have tried using `client.channels.get('ID').send("message")` and `client.channels.find('name', 'bot')` but both return `undefined`.

```js
const duckHuntChannel = client.channels.get('ID').send("I'm a duck");
// Make some ducks
function sendDuck() {
  if (huntStatus === true) {
    duckHuntChannel.send("ducc")
    setTimeout(sendDuck, Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) + 10);
  } else {
    console.log("I was gonna duck it up but I'm disabled :(");
  }
}
```

I expected the output to simply send a message to the channel. Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: You should only write `client.channels.get('ID')` if you want to savae the channel object. By writing `.send(...)` too, you're making it return a `Promise<(Message|Array<Message>)>`. You can find the docs for `TextChannel` [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)

Answer (score 0):

`client.channels.get('ID')` will return a Channel. Not to be confused with Guildchannel

Depending on which event you are, try this instead

```
message.guild.channels.get('ID')
```